# How to play the live streaming url in webview android using iframe

Tags: android, iframe, webview, streaming, live

How to load the URL streaming video in webview using iframe. This is what I have tried

```
private WebView webview;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webViewSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/frame.html");
}
```

Manifest File
Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Hardware acceleration enabled using

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

HTML CODE USED IFRAME

```
<html><body><iframe src="http://puthiyathalaimurai.tv/"></iframe></body</html>
```

Video is playing in html page But not playing in android application , can any one tell me whats the error. or whats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android lacks support for HLS, if that is what you are looking for. For detailed information on HLS Streaming support in different devices look at http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/

**I am not sure using what protocol your source URL is streaming, its better if you can provide more clarity.**

If you are looking at streaming HLS in android, you can search for some alternative 3rd party libraries or players to do the same for you or you can build your own player using FFMPEG.

Comment: We can play the live streaming in webview but i dont know i am searching for last two days . if any useful link pls share it

Comment: you cannot play live streams in webview below android 4.0

Comment: @John did you find any solution for how to play hls video by "src" link?

Comment: @NickUnuchek  i found the solution

Comment: What does that even mean "Android lacks support for HLS"? Chrome plays it. Chrome runs on Android, so that statement is obviously false.

Comment: @Nilzor: The question clearly mentions that it is not playing in android app but works in browser. When i say Android does not support HLS in pure sense, it is about the native support for HLS. Also the post is 1 year old.. not sure what it is now..

Comment: Can it not be achieved by using a chrome client within webview?